# Underscore.js doesn't substitutes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, template-engine

Lets research the following code line:

```
terminalsListHtml += this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

template:

```
compiled: _.template($('#terminal-template').text()),
```

the following selector

```
$('#terminal-template').text()
```

returns

```
"
    <li data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" class="{{ clazz2 }}">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="terminal" class="{{ clazz }}" data-terminal-id="{{ id }}"/>
            <a href="/admin/createCompany/getOriginalImage/{{imageId}}" title=""
               class="fancy_image small-picture"><img
                    src="/admin/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/{{imageId}}"
                    alt=""/></a>

            <h3>{{ name }}
                <small>{{ place }}</small>
            </h3>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>{{ count }}</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>{{ amount }}</span> руб./час</p>
        </label>
    </li>
"
```

the following code line

```
_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj)
```

returns
[image]

But after execution

```
terminalsListHtml += this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

`terminalsListHtml` equals

```
"
    <li data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" class="{{ clazz2 }}">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="terminal" class="{{ clazz }}" data-terminal-id="{{ id }}"/>
            <a href="/admin/createCompany/getOriginalImage/{{imageId}}" title=""
               class="fancy_image small-picture"><img
                    src="/admin/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/{{imageId}}"
                    alt=""/></a>

            <h3>{{ name }}
                <small>{{ place }}</small>
            </h3>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>{{ count }}</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>{{ amount }}</span> руб./час</p>
        </label>
    </li>
"
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r94snakk/) if you really have the `_.templateSettings` from your comment. Are you setting `_.templateSettings` before you call `_.template`?

Comment: @mu is too short you are right - problem was related with templateSettings location

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js templating uses EJS-style templates, while you use a different kind.  You can change the templating settings to work for your templates like so:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name: "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

This was copied from the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: I have the following code **<script type="text/javascript">
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
    };
</script>**

Comment: but I don't know if this setting uses